# Is it possible to trigger and run jobs from different processes with AdoJobStore?

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I am implementing a Windows service that's responsible for running the scheduler and executing the jobs. I want to trigger the jobs from a web application but since the web application does not run a scheduler I can't do anything with the triggers I build.

```
TriggerBuilder.Create()
              .WithIdentity(commandName,groupName)
              .ForJob(commandName)
              .StartNow()
              .Build();
```

How can I insert the trigger to the database so that the scheduler running in the Windows service can pick it up? Is this supported in Quartz.NET?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26480787/get-an-instance-of-the-scheduler-that-is-being-run-on-a-windows-service/26482361#26482361)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two layers:

- your web application will be responsible to manage (insert/delete) jobs and trigger
- your windows service will run the schedules

I've answered the same question [long time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6504528/219406) but, I guess, the implementation is pretty much the same.

Both applications will share the same database where jobs and triggers are stored.

Your web application should never start the [scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6518771/219406).